# How to mark a whole class as "Inconclusive"?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've a test class named MyClass. MyClass has a TestFixtureSetUp that loads some initial data. I want to mark whole class as Inconclusive when loading initial data fails. Just like when somebody marks a test method Inconclusive by calling Assert.Inconclusive().

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- In your `TestFixtureSetUp`, store a static value in the class to indicate whether the data has yet to be loaded, was successfully loaded, or was attempted but unsuccessfully loaded.
- In your `SetUp` for each test, check the value.
- If it indicates an unsuccessful load, immediately bomb out by calling `Assert.Inconclusive()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can work around it using `Setup` by signaling it when a data loading failed.

For example:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ClassWithDataLoad
{
    private bool loadFailed;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        // Assuming loading failure throws exception.
        // If not if-else can be used.
        try 
        {
            // Try load data
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            loadFailed = true;
        }
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        if (loadFailed)
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive();
        }
    }

    [Test] public void Test1() { }        
    [Test] public void Test2() { }
}
```

*Nunit* does not support `Assert.Inconclusive()` in the `TestFixtureSetUp`. If a call to `Assert.Inconclusive()` is done there all the tests in the fixture appear as failed.